# beautifullsoup between br tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap from the (span class= 'Number'). The code looks like this on the pages I am scrapping:

```
<div id="DetailMainBox">
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" class="styleA">
<span class="UP">99&nbsp;</span><span class="Change">10.00    (-0.1%)</span>
<span class="Portfolio"><a href="../../members/index.php" class="ThemeColor" target="_blank">Menu<img src="../images/more.gif" width="11" height="11" border="0" align="absmiddle" /></a></span>
</td>



<td class="styleB">Max Quantity<span class="RT"></span><br>
<span class="Number">100.000</span></span>  </td>

<td class="styleB">Average Quantity<span class="RT"></span><br />
<span class="Number">822</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Previous Order<br />
<span class="Number">96</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Max Price<br />
<span class="Number">104</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Number of Trades<br />
<span class="Number">383</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="styleB">Min Price<span class="RT"></span><br>
<span class="Number">59</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Total Amount<span class="RT"></span><br />
<span class="Number">800</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Start<br />
<span class="Number">10</span></td>

<td class="styleB">Low<br />
<span class="Number">98 </span></td>
```

I have tried to use Beautifulsoup to scrape the data. However, it returns Nothing on the screen

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 html = response.content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
 title =  soup.select('td.styleB')[0].next_sibling
 title1 = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'Number'}).next_sibling
 print(title1)
```

I am hoping that I could retrieve the number as follows:
Max Quantity: 100
Average Quantity: 822
Previous Order: 96
Max Price: 104
Number of Trades:383
Min Price: 59
Total Amount:800
Start:10
Low: 98

Please advise what is the problem with my code from handling the query. Thank you

Comment: for tag text try tag.string

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is as follows - dig into bs4 more, you may get to a more efficient and elegant solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("bs4_test.html"), "html.parser")
tds = soup.select('td.styleB')
for td in tds:
    num = td.select('span.Number')
    for i in num:
        print ("{0} : {1}".format(td.next_element, i.string))
```

The `bs4_test.html` is the html you shared - the above lines output:

```
Max Quantity : 100.000
Average Quantity : 822
Previous Order : 96
Max Price : 104
Number of Trades : 383
Min Price : 59
Total Amount : 800
Start : 10
Low : 98
```

---

The bs4_test.html for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="DetailMainBox">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="styleA" rowspan="2"><span class=
                "UP">99&nbsp;</span><span class="Change">10.00 (-0.1%)</span>
                <span class="Portfolio"><a class="ThemeColor" href=
                "../../members/index.php" target="_blank">Menu<img align=
                "absmiddle" border="0" height="11" src="../images/more.gif"
                width="11"></a></span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Max Quantity<span class="RT"></span><br>
                <span class="Number">100.000</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Average Quantity<span class="RT"></span><br>
                <span class="Number">822</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Previous Order<br>
                <span class="Number">96</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Max Price<br>
                <span class="Number">104</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Number of Trades<br>
                <span class="Number">383</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="styleB">Min Price<span class="RT"></span><br>
                <span class="Number">59</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Total Amount<span class="RT"></span><br>
                <span class="Number">800</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Start<br>
                <span class="Number">10</span></td>
                <td class="styleB">Low<br>
                <span class="Number">98</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the solution is for what you asked in the question - if you have something new/different to ask post it as a separate question